# File is not opened by Package Installer when using intent type application/vnd.android.package-archive

Tags: android, apk, packageinstaller

This is my code:

```
i.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_NOT_UNKNOWN_SOURCE, true);
i.setDataAndType(Uri.parse(FileUtil.getPublicDir(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOWNLOADS).concat("/Vertretungsplan.apk")), "application/vnd.android.package-archive");
i.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
```

However, when I start the activity, the Package Installer won't show as "open with".

Answer (score 2):

That is not a valid `Uri`. A `Uri` has a scheme; the value that you are trying to parse does not.

On Android 6.0 and below, use `Uri.fromFile()` to build the `Uri` for your file.

On Android 7.0+, since the `file` scheme is banned, you will need to configure `FileProvider` for your app and use a `Uri` from it. Unfortunately, that *won't* work for Android 6.0 and below, as the package installer could not handle `content` `Uri` values back then. So, you need to check the version of Android that your app is running on and use the appropriate approach.

Comment: That's not the problem, the Uri is valid.

Comment: @RichardS.: No, it is not. It has no scheme. You can tell that by logging its value to Logcat, or by inspecting it in a debugger. Also note that your `Intent` seems to lack an action. I am guessing that you are using `ACTION_VIEW`. If so, you will need to fix your `Uri` to have a scheme (`file` for Android 6.0 and below, `content` for Android 7.0 and above), as I wrote in the answer.

Comment: I left the first lines out to minimize the code. The Uri has the right scheme and the intent also has the `ACTION_VIEW` action.

Comment: @RichardS.: "The Uri has the right scheme" -- then perhaps you should edit your question and post the actual code. The code in your question results in a `Uri` without a scheme.

Answer (score 1):

Add `REQUEST_INSTALL_PACKAGES` permission to your manifest